# RavenDB Nested Object Projection from Static Index

Tags: c#, ravendb, nosql

If I have a static index in RavenDB that looks like this:

```
public class TestIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<CardApplication>
{
   public TestIndex()
   {
        Map = apps =>
            from app in apps
            select new { State = app.State, };

        Sort(c => c.State, Raven.Abstractions.Indexing.SortOptions.String);
   }
}
```

And then I try to query it using:

```
session.Query<CardApplication, TestIndex>()
    .OrderBy(c => c.State)
    .Select(c => new { c.State, c.IdentityDetails.Applicant.FirstName, })
    .ToList();
```

I get results back where the State properties are set, but the FirstName properties are all null.

When I look at the HTTP requests RavenDB is sending over the wire, I find it is using a query string parameter: `fetch=IdentityDetails_Applicant_FirstName`. If I modify that to `fetch=IdentityDetails.Applicant.FirstName` and reissue the request, I get the correct results back (at least in the returned JSON I can see the FirstName results).

If I do a similar query using dynamic indexes:

```
session.Query<CardApplication>()
    .OrderBy(c => c.State)
    .Select(c => new { c.State, c.IdentityDetails.Applicant.FirstName, })
    .ToList();
```

I get the correct results back, and I notice that RavenDB has sent the correct dot-separated path in the HTTP request, rather than the broken underscore separated one.

How can I get this nested object projection to work with static indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked RavenDB to fetch the property from the index, so you need to actually specify the property.
Use the following index:

```
public class TestIndex : AbstractIndexCreationTask<CardApplication>
{
   public TestIndex()
   {
        Map = apps =>
            from app in apps
            select new { State = app.State, IdentityDetails_Applicant_FirstName = app IdentityDetails.Applicant.FirstName};

        Sort(c => c.State, Raven.Abstractions.Indexing.SortOptions.String);
 Store("IdentityDetails_Applicant_FirstName", FieldStorage.Yes);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Why is it that I don't need to Store the State property, but I do need to Store FirstName? Even if I remove the Sort, I still always get its value back. Is it to do with it being an Enum type rather than a string?